# Slow file parsing when using .split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

```
with open(file, 'r') as h:
    f = h.readlines()
    for line in f:
        a = line.split()[-7]
        if a in dict:
           dict[a] += line
        else:
            dict[a] = line
```

I found a lot of questions on here about parsing files but none about the speed of the parse. Most people were looking for "how to parse file" and "how to collect x from file" and the answers were usually something like my example above. Im looking for any way to speed this up.

Parsing a 30MB files with 276,000 lines will take ~50 minutes with the above process. If I take the split out of the process then it finishes in less than 1 second. Knowing that im always looking for the same index on every line, is it possible to do this any faster?

Comment: Try: `string.rsplit(..., 8)[1]` - splitting from the right instead of the left.

Comment: You can pass arguments to `split` to limit how much splitting it actually does. In your case, you might be better off using `rsplit` which will split from the right side of the string instead. That could leave you with `a = line.rsplit(None, 7)[-7]`. Does that help performance?

Comment: When you "take the split out of the process", what are you doing instead?  Are you still checking `if a in dict`?  If so, how are you getting `a`?

Comment: For faster processing, this problem can be parallelized by having a number of threads (one per CPU) all working on a separate part of the file.  The dictionaries resulting from each thread can be merged when all lines have been processed.

Comment: Python cannot take advantage of multiple CPU threads at once, because of the Global Interpreter Lock.

Comment: @JohnGordon I would just check if line is in dict. This results in a dictionary with more keys and less values. Guess that could result effect the time as well but with most lines having timestamps its hard to test this.

Comment: @Shadow i'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: `dict[a] += line` is likely the culprit.  String concatenation is _slow_.

Comment: @JohnGordon you are right. if I append to a normal list it finishes quickly. When I removed the split in my test it would just create a new key in the dictionary and that went through fast. The first thing that comes to mind is appending to different list and working with those some how. Any other way around this concatenation slowness?

Comment: Following John's suggestion: Use `from collections import defaultdict; d = defaultdict(list)`. Replace *entire* `if` statement with `d.append(line)`. Which means to say, keep a *list* of all of the lines in each dictionary entry. Then make a separate pass in another loop through this dictionary, to create another dictionary, the result, that has the same keys but whose items are the concatenations of the lists in `d`.